# .htaccess - url ending char (/)

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

please help me with modifications .htaccess. How add ending character [/] in url.

Now .htaccess doing 
www.mysite.cz/about.php > www.mysite.cz/about 
www.mysite.cz/about/ > www.mysite.cz/about

i need this 
www.mysite.cz/about.php > www.mysite.cz/about/ 
www.mysite.cz/about > www.mysite.cz/about/

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.cz$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mysite.cz/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index.php$ http://mysite.cz/$1 [R=301,L]      

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+(.+)(?:/|\.php)(?:\?|\ )
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php    [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.cz$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mysite.cz/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(index.php)$ http://mysite.cz/$1 [NC,R=301,L]      

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+(.+)(?:/|\.php)(?:\?|\ )
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ /%1/ [NC,L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ $1.php    [NC,L]
```

This adds a trailing slash at  the end of the path :

```
 www.mydomain.cz/about.php
```

would redirect to

```
  www.mydomain.cz/about/
```

Comment: This solution does not work - browser reports an error [ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS]